# Assigning ivars using self keyword in an object's init method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization, instance-variables, self

I've read that it's bad to use self.ivar = (convenience method) in and object's 'init' method, as this messes with inheritance.

However, if you know you're not going to subclass your object, is it ok to use the self keyword assignment?

```
i.e. self.iVar = [Object objectConvenienceMethod];
```

The reason I ask is this. I create a new object with its own init method, and in that method, I perform various initial assignments. Since I don't use the self keyword, I assign them directly to the iVars, and therefore use the alloc methods rather than the convenience methods. I.e.

```
iVar = [[Object alloc] init];
```

Or if I use a convenience method, I retain it. I.e.

```
iVar = [[Object convenienceMethod]retain]
```

But... when I run my program with the memory leak tool on, all of these assignments are identified as memory leaks.

If I can use the self keyword plus a convenience method instead of alloc-init, then this would avoid the problem.

If I choose to use the alloc-init approach though, where am I supposed to release the iVars?? Just in dealloc?

Thanks for your help :)

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking your "enclosing" class is not being released, and hence its dealloc method is not being called resulting in your iVars not being released.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is being released, since I've put NSLog statements in both deallocs and they're being printed correctly. What I'm thinking may be the case is how I initially create the object. I initialise it, passing it an instance of it's own parent to set the initial values. In it's init method, it saves itself to file, so I release the newly inited object as soon as I've alloced it. This doesn't go down too well and crashes, so I don't dealloc it. But I don't know what else to do... I've tried autoreleasing it but this crashes too.

Comment: Maybe you have created a circular reference using strong links. How are you storing the link to the parent? Are you retaining the link to the parent? Usually, when children link to parents it should be through a weak link (not retained).

Comment: You might want to check out the section "Weak References to Objects" in the document: [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

No, because it isn't only subclass behavior you need to take into account — superclass implementations and even the behavior of code generated by the framework (e.g. synthesized accessors and the black magic used to implement KVO) can also cause trouble. It will *probably* be OK, but that's still a significant chance of being not-OK. All in all, it's best just to follow Apple's recommendation and assign directly.

Assigning to ivars in init shouldn't be reported as leaks in a properly functioning program. If you're seeing that, there's some other problem that you need to address. Try reducing the problem to a minimal case that we can try out and ask about that — then we can tell what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I've figured out what the other problem is now - it's how I initialise the new object... I've written a new question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/334296/smikey if you have time to take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

If you `alloc` or `retain` them in your class's `init` method, you should release them in the corresponding `dealloc` method.

Comment: Strictly it's the `alloc` rather than `init` that you need to balance, but they normally go hand in hand.

Comment: But I do release them in the dealloc method - however the leak detector still identifies them as leaking, whenever I create a new instance of the object?? :(

Comment: If your retains/allocs and releases are balanced, then you won't leak memory. Are you sure they aren't being retained anywhere else?

Comment: Yeah - I'm certain. I searched for all instances of the iVars in question in the class, and they're only released in the dealloc... Could it be something to do with the fact that the class is a subclass, and the parent class does not declare it's own init method since it doesn't need to initialise any instance variables...?

Comment: If you're leaking memory, you're not over-releasing, you're over-retaining. I don't think the parent class has anything to do with it (as long as it isn't leaking its own instance variables).

Comment: Also, the class conforms to NSCoding. The initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder methods use the accessors to save and load the iVars... would this mess with the retain count perhaps? I've made sure that every time I've referenced the ivars outside of the init method, I've used the accessor methods.

Comment: As long as you use the accessors, then you should be fine.

Comment: Could I be over retaining by using the accessor methods from outside the class? I've combed my code and I really can't see how I could be over retaining the ivars within the class.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have found it. When I initialise and instance of the class which is leaking from another class, I have a funny problem. If I initialise it using the init method I have written (which happens to use another object to determine initial values, then saves itself to memory) and then immediately release it (since it saves itself to memory when it initialises), it crashes. So I have to send it a retain count which means it's over retained. However I can't release it without it crashing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Should I not be saving the object within its own init??